# PHP echo doesn't echo certain output

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

So I've been fooling around on a very simple design for a database that has a feature to allow an admin to log in and edit some of the products. This is the current layout of getting the username and password from the log in form:

```
$manager = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"];
$manager = stripslashes($manager);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$manager = mysql_real_escape_string($manager);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

I've created log in scripts before but for some reason I'm having trouble with this log in actually working. So I was checking what some variables were being passed as in order to see where the problem was occurring when I got to these lines:

```
echo "manager = " . $manager . "<br />";
echo "password = " . $password . "<br />";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password'";
echo $sql;
```

The output was:

```
manager = scott
password = password123
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='scott' AND password=''
```

where the $password variable was removed from the output of the $sql string. Any suggestions on why it is leaving out the $password variable?

Here is the HTML form code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin_login.php">
    Username:<br />
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

Comment: It's working on my local

Comment: does your password starts by a "<" ? if so it may be interpreted as a tag by most browser, check html source of your page.

Comment: The form is passing the correct data to the script. echo "Password passed via form = " . $_POST["password"] . "<br />"; prints out: Password passed via form = password123

Comment: Could you show the html form code please.

Comment: @Darren updated to show html code

Comment: You should really just forget about this, switch to PDO or mysqli using prepared statements and use a salted hash for your passwords. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and getting the passwords right from the start will save you a lot of work later on.

Comment: My guess is that it's being mistaken for SQL's `PASSWORD()` function. Try wrapping `password` with backticks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you were correct. Changed the variable of $password and now the query works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: SQL uses `password()` as a function and will not show a password for security reasons when using that word. Here's some documentation on it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question:

SQL uses `password()` as a function and will not show a password for security reasons when using that word. Here's some documentation on it:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

Therefore, use another name for the password variable.

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='" .$manager. "' And password='" .$password. "';
```

Try this

Comment: @steven my query is based on the output that op has posted.

Comment: I assume you want OP to replace the line he has that starts with `$sql` with the line that you posted. But they are functionally the same, it can't solve anything.

Comment: I agree with @steven.